# Word count using STL

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, stl

How to count the number of words in a paragraph from specified position using STL Algorithm?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>    
#include <functional>
#include <string> 


inline unsigned CountWords( const std::string& s )        
{    
std::string x = s;
std::replace_if( x.begin(), x.end(), std::ptr_fun <int, int> ( std::isspace ), ' ' );
x.erase( 0, x.find_first_not_of( " " ) );
if (x.empty()) return 0;
return std::count( x.begin(), std::unique( x.begin(), x.end() ), ' ' ) + !std::isspace(           *s.regin() );         
}
```

Comment: For those who need an explanation of this excellent answer, the following may help. std::replace_if replaces all white space characters with space. The call to erase strips all white space characters from the beginning of the string. The call to std::unique returns a new string in which all consecutive duplicate spaces are removed. The call to std::count returns the number of spaces, and thus words, in the string returned by std::unique. Finally either 0 or 1 is added to the resulting count depending on whether or not the original string begins in a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count_words(const char *input_buf) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << input_buf;
    string word;
    int words = 0;
    while(ss >> word) words++;
    return words;
}
```